# prettyPhoto loads on browser refresh

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I've used prettyPhoto to display galleries, YouTube and Flash, but I'm having a "refresh" problem when I use single images. prettyPhoto opens when I click on a thumbnail and it appends #!prettyPhoto/0/ to the querystring. But when prettyPhoto closes it's not removing the /0/, so the same image opens again when the page is refreshed. I've looked at the demo page and it removes the /0/.

My code couldn't be any simpler. Any thoughts about how to remove the /0/ or keep prettyPhoto from loading on refresh?

```
<link href="css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" lang="en" xml:lang="en" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<a href="/templates/template9.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is the description"><img src="/templates/template9.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="This is the title" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({social_tools:false,theme:'light_rounded'});});
</script>
```

My development page: http://www.sremarketing.com/untitled-3.html

Answer (score 1):

I was using pp 3.1.2 with the new release (3.1.3) this issue is fixed.